# handle permissions with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, client

I'm building a new project with backbone and I was wondering what is the best approach to handle user's permissions with it. e.g. if I want that for some users a specific control will not be rendered. where the logic for it should be? I was thinking maybe checking this on the initialize function of the View and wrapping the render function with it. what would you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All security tasks like authorization and authentication should be managed by the server.
It's so easy to bypass them in the client, making all auth/acl operations in client irrelevant.
Use session and cookies to manage this via server implementation.

see the userSession.js file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application/11598371#11598371)

Comment: i'm not sure this is what I need. the way it's used is     if(!userSession.authenticated()){
               App.Router.navigate('login', {trigger: true});
           }
it looks like we have a model: userSession which holds flags on the user permissions and if he doesn't have a permission we redirect to another page. I need permission on the control level, not page level

Comment: check the controller.js file you can choose what to render according to the "role" property for instance, for admin render this and that and for manager or regular user you cane choose to render something else, but once again this is very easy to bypass, you should serve via server the code you want to run according to login or other credentials

Answer (score 1):

I would refer you to Addy Osmany's [Large Scale Javascript](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) paper. He describes the idea of `Facade` which is also responsible for handling permissions.

The [aura](http://addyosmani.github.com/aura/) project intended to apply this concept, but for now the permissions feature is missing there, as for me.